# Why is the following Puppeteer script giving an 'undefined' for ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm learning the Puppeteer API at the moment and am using v1.9.0.  I have the following code from where I'm trying to click a button within an iframe:

```js
const changePrefsFromAllToNone = async () => {

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless:false,
            slowMo: 250});

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 800});
        await page.goto(baseUrl);
        await page.waitForSelector('.widget-title');
        const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframe');
        const prefsDenyButton = await frame.$eval('#option-refuse-phv1L');
        prefsDenyButton.click();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

changePrefsFromAllToNone();
```

with an error of:

```
Error: The following is not a function: undefined
at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle
```

I'm using the example direct from the puppeteer website:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.9.0/docs/api.md#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [query selector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.9.0/docs/api.md#frameselector), not for `eval`. You also missed an `await`. This should work:

```
        const prefsDenyButton = await frame.$('#option-refuse-phv1L');
        await prefsDenyButton.click();
```